# How to add p-values onto a grouped ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, t-test

| fish_ID | color | inst | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | inst_0 | 136 |
| 1 | green | inst_0 | 40 |
| 1 | red | inst_0 | 111 |
| 1 | yellow | inst_0 | 20 |
| 1 | blue | inst_3 | 112 |
| 1 | green | inst_3 | 13 |
| 1 | red | inst_3 | 15 |
| 1 | yellow | inst_3 | 90 |
| 2 | blue | inst_0 | 110 |
| 2 | green | inst_0 | 80 |
| 2 | red | inst_0 | 11 |
| 2 | yellow | inst_0 | 34 |
| 2 | blue | inst_3 | 19 |
| 2 | green | inst_3 | 130 |
| 2 | red | inst_3 | 15 |
| 2 | yellow | inst_3 | 88 |

I am giving here a part of data as an example. I have many fish ID number like this. I want to do a paired t-test,comparing the mean time spent between inst_0 and inst_3 for every color set. I was able to compare them nicely with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggprism)

ggplot(mydata , aes(x = factor(inst), y = time, fill = color)) +
 geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue" = "blue", "green" = "green", "red" = "red", "yellow" = 
 "yellow")) +
 theme_prism()
```

I want to also add p values from paired t-test results on the graph but I am not sure how to apply the pairwise comparison for each color set(for example comparison for blue between inst_0 and inst_3). I would apprecaite your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: As you are using ggprism package, there is an example on how to add the pvalue, did you try? https://csdaw.github.io/ggprism/ and https://csdaw.github.io/ggprism/articles/pvalues.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I tried but it gives an error. "Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'p.adj' not found". For 'df_p_val', it doesn't create this 'p.adj' and 'p.adj.signif' columns.

Comment: You will need to create those table yourself. Or look into ggpubr where it adds pvalues automatically http://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could align the location of p-values after using `rstatix`.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           fish_ID = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                       2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L),
             Color = c("blue","green","red",
                       "yellow","blue","green","red","yellow","blue","green",
                       "red","yellow","blue","green","red","yellow"),
              inst = c("inst_0","inst_0","inst_0",
                       "inst_0","inst_3","inst_3","inst_3","inst_3","inst_0",
                       "inst_0","inst_0","inst_0","inst_3","inst_3",
                       "inst_3","inst_3"),
              time = c(136L,40L,111L,20L,112L,13L,
                       15L,90L,110L,80L,11L,34L,19L,130L,15L,88L)
)

library(rstatix)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggprism)

df_p_val <- df |> 
  group_by(Color) |>  
  t_test(time ~ inst) |>  
  add_xy_position()

# align positions of p-values
df_p_val <- df_p_val |> 
  mutate(group1 = c(0.7,0.9, 1.1, 1.3),
         group2 = c(1.7, 1.9, 2.1,2.3))

colors <- unique(df$Color) # to manually select fill, color scales
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(inst), y=time)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Color)) +
  theme_prism() +
  add_pvalue(df_p_val, fontface="bold", 
             colour = "Color", 
             show.legend=F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values =colors) +
  scale_color_manual(values=colors)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>