# How to align the p values between the corresponding boxplot along the x axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

[image]

My question is how can I align the p values just between the corresponding boxplots along the x axis. Here is my code which is a bit mess but it works:

```
p <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=factor(instance), y=time))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Color))+
  theme_prism()

p + add_pvalue(df_p_val, 
           label = "p = {p.format}",
           colour = "Color",
           fontface = "bold",
           step.group.by = "Color",
           step.increase = 0.1,
           tip.length = 0,
           bracket.colour = "black",
           show.legend = FALSE,
           y.position = c(350, 400, 450,500))
```

Comment: Is that using the `ggprism` package?

Comment: I answered [your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76178130/11926169). Then you could handle this problem.
BTW, it would be very helpful if you provide at least sample of your data using `dput(my data)` and `dput(df_p_val)`.